# Convert datatable to tree-like class structure

Tags: c#, datatable

I have this datatable

```
Name    Amount  Category
sample  100.00  1
sample  100.00  1
aasdas  11.00   1
asd     1.00    2
sadjas  1.00    2
sadjas  1.00    2
asdasd  1.00    3
asdasd  1.00    3
test    10.00   3
```

And I have this class

```
public class ProductListModel
{
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public List<ProductModel> prodList { get; set; }
}
```

And each instance of this class contains a list of product models with this definition

```
public class ProductModel
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
}
```

How can I convert this datatable  to fit on the definition of `ProductListModel` class?

So the output would be in this form (for visualization only) :

```
// Group by category 1
-- ProductListModel
     --CategoryName = 1
     -- ProdList 
        -- Name = sample, amount = 100.00       
        -- Name = sample, amount = 100.00       
        -- Name = aasdas, amount = 11.00   

// Group by category 2
-- ProductListModel
     --CategoryName = 2
     -- ProdList 
        -- Name = asd, amount = 1.00       
        -- Name = sadjas, amount = 1.00       
        -- Name = sadjas, amount = 1.00      

// Group by category 3      
-- ProductListModel
     --CategoryName = 3
     -- ProdList 
        -- Name = asdasd, amount = 1.00       
        -- Name = asdasd, amount = 1.00
```

I tried but I'm stuck :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "simplify" it like this

```
var productList = datatable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
    .GroupBy(r => r["Category"] + "").Select(g => new ProductListModel {
        CategoryName = g.Key,
        prodList = g.Select(r => new ProductModel {
            Name = r["Name"] + "",
            Amount = (double)r["Amount"]
        }).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Could this be it? This will put the categories in a list and put the respective products inside the categories. (This is untested though)

```
List<ProductListModel> productCategories = new List<ProductListModel>();

foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows) // Go through all data rows
{
    if (!productCategories.Any(pc => pc.CategoryName == (string)row[2])) // if the product's category is not registered
        productCategories.Add(new ProductListModel() { CategoryName = (string)row[2] } ); // Then add the category to the category list

    // Add the current product (row) to the first registered category that matches the product's own
    productCategories.First(pc => pc.CategoryName == (string)row[2]).prodList.Add(new ProductModel() 
    { 
        Name = (string)row[0], 
        Amount = double.Parse((string)row[1]) 
    }); 
}
```

I hope this helps.

**Edit**

I changed the code a bit so that repeating products will get their ammouts stacked (if that makes sense):

```
List<ProductListModel> productCategories = new List<ProductListModel>();

foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
{
    if (!productCategories.Any(pc => pc.CategoryName == (string)row[2]))
        productCategories.Add(new ProductListModel() { CategoryName = (string)row[2] });

    ProductListModel currentCategory = productCategories.First(pc => pc.CategoryName == (string)row[2]);

    if (currentCategory.prodList.Any(pr => pr.Name == (string)row[0]))
        currentCategory.prodList.First(pr => pr.Name == (string)row[0]).Amount += double.Parse((string)row[1]);
    else
        currentCategory.prodList.Add(new ProductModel() { Name = (string)row[0], Amount = double.Parse((string)row[1]) });
}
```

Comment: thansk for the effort but it's not working, can this be done without looping?

Comment: How is it not working? What goes wrong? What is the outcome vs what you expect? What is wrong with looping?

Comment: @Sherlock I made some changes to the code. Maybe you didn't get that when you copied the code. I also made another version.

Comment: thanks for the help bro, you give me some insight on how to do it. I will just upvote but will not accept as answer

Comment: Did you make it work or can you manage? Did you make your own solution?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this

```
List<ProductListModel> productList = new List<ProductListModel>();

foreach (var row in datatable.AsEnumerable())
{
    var categoryId = row.Field<string>("Category");
    var product = new ProductModel
    {
        Name = row.Field<string>("Name"),
        Amount = row.Field<double>("Amount")
    };

    // Build each category
    if (!productList.Any(x => x.CategoryName == categoryId))
    {
        var itemList = new List<ProductModel>();

        itemList.Add(product);
        productList.Add(new ProductListModel { CategoryName = categoryId, prodList = itemList });
    }
    else
    {
        var existingprodList = productList.Where(x => x.CategoryName == categoryId).FirstOrDefault();
        existingprodList.prodList.Add(product);
    }
}
```